# What's the best way to hold features in a database?

Tags: database-design

taking for example an application that holds **Companies** and as we move along time, more and more features are needed.

I do tend to hold everything in the `Companies` table, but I rather get some input as I'm starting a new project and was wondering if I should keep those in a `CompanyFeatures` table:

[image]

Should I have 2 tables, or this flow is enough?

I have the same for users, each user has it's own on/off feature (when a feature can be user specific), should I continue to keep them there, or should also create a `UserFeatures` table to hold such information?

Every time I get a company, all of their associated features information needs to be "glued", but it's an easy join and the query will be cached for the next request... Querying the DB should never be a problem, my question is more about design patterns and if such information should have it's place.

Comment: That depends on how often you are going to retrieve companies *with* all of their associated features and *without* a lot of them. The commoner an "abridged" info is sufficient, the more sense it makes to have a separate table that is only queried as necessary.

Comment: @KilianFoth every time I get a company, such information needs to be "glued", but it's an easy `join` and the query will be cached for the next request... Querying the DB should never be a problem, my question is more about design patterns and if such information should have it's place.

Comment: What do the prefixes "perm" and "gko" mean ?

Comment: @user61852 `perm = permission` and `gko = our main company alias`